# Error catching with try-catch and while loop

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to make sure that the users input is an integer but when I use the below code I just get an infinite loop of the `print` statement. Any advice of how to improve?

```
boolean valid = false;
System.out.println("What block are you gathering? (use minecraft block ids)");
while(valid == false){
    try{
        block = input.nextInt();
        valid = true;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException exception){
        System.out.println("What block are you gathering? (use minecraft block ids)");
        valid = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What type is `block`?

Comment: @UmaKanth  Doesn't matter here :).

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? ive used NumberFormatException but get this error instead :
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at firsttry.Main.main(Main.java:28)

Comment: Also it's always better practice to write `while(!valid)` rather than `while(valid == false)`

Comment: @Tom Nice find! That's exactly the problem.

Comment: what is input in your code block?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Well, it is like "why is nextLine() skipped after nextInt()" ... these questions were asked and answered hundreds of times before :D. Just needed to find one of them.

Comment: Sorry about asking a duplicate question i did try and find an answer but guess i didn't look hard enough. thanks for the help everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nextInt()` doesn't consume invalid input so it will try read same invalid value over and over again. To solve this problem you need to consume it explicitly by calling `next()` or `nextLine()` which accept any value.

BTW to make your code cleaner and avoid expensive operations like creating exceptions you should use methods like `hasNextInt()` .

Here is how you can organize your code

```
System.out.println("What block are you gathering? (use minecraft block ids)");
while(!input.hasNextInt()){
    input.nextLine();// consume invalid values until end of line, 
                     // use next() if you want to consume them one by one.
    System.out.println("That is not integer. Please try again");
}
//here we are sure that next element will be int, so lets read it
block = input.nextInt();
```